# It's been a week since the middle exam is over

Tags: translation

How to turn this sentence into chinese?

It's been a week since the middle exam is over

Comment: Check Google Translate.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "middle exam"? If you mean the second of three, then I'd say 第二个考试以后已经过了一个星期的时间

Comment: I think the middle exam might be 期中考试.

Comment: Ah ok, "mid-term exam" would be the correct way to say it then. And the Chinese would be 期中考试以后已经过了一个星期的时间